# cURL options not working well with php

Tags: php, curl

I've been writing some php script ..

```
$gettarget = $argv[2];
echo "Trying to do something . . .\n";
            sleep(2);
            $ch = curl_init($gettarget); // initialize curl with given url
            $useragent = "Some user agent ";
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $useragent); // add useragent

            $response = curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); // write the response to a variable
echo $response;
echo "Done";
```

So  here's what happens , It comes to " Trying to do something " and then nothing happens and the Done doesn't get echoed that means there's something wrong with curl , I don't really know what is up with cURL , So I thought I would post here.

Comment: You have not executed curl yet, in this code block. Need a `$response = curl_exec( $ch );` at the end.

Comment: You mean curl_exec(); ?

Comment: Yes, see answer below and give it a spin.

Comment: I did , And it still didn't get past curl

Answer (score 1):

You have not executed curl yet, in this code block. Need a `$response = curl_exec( $ch );` at the end.

```
    $gettarget = $argv[2];
    echo "Trying to do something . . .\n";

    sleep(2);
    $ch = curl_init($gettarget); // initialize curl with given url
    $useragent = "Some user agent ";
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $useragent); // add useragent

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); // setopt() does not exec()

    // write the response to a variable
    $response = curl_exec( $ch );

    echo $response;
    echo "Done";
```

Answer (score 1):

`$response = curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);`

should be

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
```

The `curl_setopt()` call tells it to return the response when you call `curl_exec()`